# extract glmboost model coefficient

Tags: r, regression, boosting

I have a model fitted with glmboost function from mboost package.
The object name of the fitted model is modelResult.
When trying to extra the coefficient of the model. I observed different results from the below two calls, which is causing the confusion.

1. modelResult$coef()
2. coefficients(modelResult)

The second call is consistent with the result returned by predict(modelResult) and the first one has a different intercept value.

Can someone please explain what are the difference between the two calls?

Comment: To answer myself, option 1 is not on the original scale and are for use by the coef method according to r document. So never use 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `mboost` package is implemented in such a way that an offset is used to initialize the estimation of the base learners. To obtain coefficient estimates in a (generalized) linear model that are comparable to the usual OLS/ML estimates, this offset needs to be added to the intercept. Therefore, the `coef()` method has an argument `off2int` that can be set to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

For more details, I would recommend to look at the tutorial paper: Hofner B, Mayr A, Robinzonov N, Schmid M (2014). "Model-Based Boosting in R: A Hands-On Tutorial Using the R Package mboost." *Computational Statistics*, **29**(1), 3-35. [doi:10.1007/s00180-012-0382-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00180-012-0382-5)